# Subtract two values from the same column

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join

I want to subtract two values from the same column like this:

```
SELECT tblTask.CustomerName,
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(Value AS FLOAT), 0)) AS summa
FROM   tblExtraFieldData
       INNER JOIN tblTask
               ON tblExtraFieldData.OwnerId = tblTask.Id
       INNER JOIN tblLog
               ON tblExtraFieldData.OwnerId = tblLog.OwnerId
WHERE  tblLog.Modified BETWEEN '2016-11-25' AND '2016-12-31'
       AND tblExtraFieldData.FieldId = '10052'
       AND tblTask.Status = '5'
       AND tblLog.Text LIKE '%Exporterat%'
       AND tblTask.ProjectNr NOT LIKE 'Fastpris'
GROUP  BY tblTask.CustomerName
ORDER  BY summa
```

And now I want to subtract this with a value that is found in tblExtraFieldData.Value and the FieldId = '10048' in the table tblExtraFieldData

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: You can add tblExtraFieldData in the from clause with different alias, and add the `alias.FieldId='10048'` clause in where part.

Comment: I deleted my answer -- next time don't link to soft core porn NSFW sites and at least be able to know what a subtraction operation is -- since you ask for one in your question.